# bindingComponent parameter must be an instance of DataBindingComponent

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

So I'm using data binding in my Android project and having an issue with one class.

**Crash Log:**

> The provided bindingComponent parameter must be an instance of DataBindingComponent

The project is using Android support libraries and not Android. No issues while generating DatanBinding class. Below is the code snippet

```
public BaseBrowserAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater from = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext());
        if (i == 32 || i == 128) {
            return new MediaViewHolder(BrowserItemBinding.inflate(from, viewGroup)); //Error at here, BrowserItemBinding
        }
        return new SeparatorViewHolder(BrowserItemSeparatorBinding.inflate(from, viewGroup));
    }
```

**Here is the browser_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout>
    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View"/>
        <import type="android.text.TextUtils"/>
        <import type="com.test.media.MediaLibraryItem"/>
        <variable
            name="holder"
            type="com.test.subtitle_browser.BaseBrowserAdapter.ViewHolder"/>
        <variable
            name="item"
            type="MediaLibraryItem"/>
        <variable
            name="title"
            type="String"/>
        <variable
            name="hasContextMenu"
            type="boolean"/>
        <variable
            name="checkEnabled"
            type="boolean"/>
        <variable
            name="checked"
            type="boolean"/>
        <variable
            name="protocol"
            type="String"/>
        <variable
            name="cover"
            type="android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable"/>
        <variable
            name="bgColor"
            type="int" />
    </data>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background_item"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:minHeight="50.0dip"
    android:padding="2.0dip"

    >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/browser_checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="false"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dvi_icon"
        android:layout_width="50.0dip"
        android:layout_height="50.0dip"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cover_art"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/whitetransparent"
        android:textSize="11.0sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/browser_checkbox"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5.0dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="?list_title"
        android:textSize="16.0sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_more"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/dvi_icon"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_goneMarginBottom="2.0dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="?list_subtitle"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/item_more"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/title"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_more"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_more_player"
        android:paddingLeft="10.0dip"
        android:paddingRight="10.0dip"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

Thank you so much in advance. Let me know if you need any more details.